# Unable to Instantiate Class while Alter Region adding cache loaded to that region

Tags: gemfire, geode, spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

I have an apache geode setup where there is one locator and one Server. we have a region employee in that. we were trying to implement in-line cache where a cache miss will lookup into database and will fill apache geode, but after deployment of Jars when i am trying to alter the region . It shows exception

```
Stack Trace:
[error 2021/04/09 15:18:30.513 IST <Function Execution Processor2> tid=0x3a] Error instantiating class: <com.abc.geode.ApacheGeode.EmployeeCacheLoader>
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error instantiating class: <com.abc.geode.ApacheGeode.EmployeeCacheLoader>
    at org.apache.geode.management.internal.configuration.domain.DeclarableTypeInstantiator.newInstance(DeclarableTypeInstantiator.java:43)
    at org.apache.geode.management.internal.cli.functions.RegionAlterFunction.alterRegion(RegionAlterFunction.java:202)
    at org.apache.geode.management.internal.cli.functions.RegionAlterFunction.executeFunction(RegionAlterFunction.java:67)
    at org.apache.geode.management.cli.CliFunction.execute(CliFunction.java:37)
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.MemberFunctionStreamingMessage.process(MemberFunctionStreamingMessage.java:201)
    at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.DistributionMessage.scheduleAction(DistributionMessage.java:372)
    at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.DistributionMessage$1.run(DistributionMessage.java:436)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.ClusterOperationExecutors.runUntilShutdown(ClusterOperationExecutors.java:475)
    at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.ClusterOperationExecutors.doFunctionExecutionThread(ClusterOperationExecutors.java:393)
    at org.apache.geode.logging.internal.executors.LoggingThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(LoggingThreadFactory.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.abc.geode.ApacheGeode.EmployeeCacheLoader cannot be cast to org.apache.geode.cache.Declarable
    at org.apache.geode.management.internal.configuration.domain.DeclarableTypeInstantiator.newInstance(DeclarableTypeInstantiator.java:34)
```

```
public class EmployeeCacheLoader implements CacheLoader<Long,Employee>, Declarable {

    @Override
    public Employee load(LoaderHelper<Long, Employee> helper) throws CacheLoaderException {
       Employee e=new Employee();
       e.setEmail("a@b.com");
       e.setIdemployee(2L);
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Properties props) {
       }
```

Things tried

1. I tried by not implementing Declarable but still no success.
2. I have not done any change for serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried the scenario using Apache Geode `1.13.2` and it works just fine, you can find the example [here](https://github.com/jujoramos/stackoverflow/tree/main/cache-loader-gfsh-alter-region-67019639). Do you have multiple versions of the same jar within the server's class path?, that might be the reason for the exception.

Cheers.

Comment: While starting server i gave class path location and it worked. Earlier i was creating server and then deploying jars using deploy command. Not sure why that is not working.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working!. Nevertheless, deploying the jar and altering the region after it's created should work as well... in fact, that's the approach I've used in the example I previously shared (see [here](https://github.com/jujoramos/stackoverflow/blob/main/cache-loader-gfsh-alter-region-67019639/reproducer.sh#L21-L26)). Cheers.

Comment: sorry Juan for going off topic but one question can i create materialized view in apache geode ?

Comment: Just replied in your newly created stackoverflow question, long story short: no, you can't.